# Maximizing time between events when scheduling

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

Suppose I have some set of events $E$, each associated with a collection of time periods $P$ that these events occur, where $P_1$ is earlier than $P_2$. For example:

$$
\begin{align}
E_1 &\rightarrow \{P_1, P_2, P_3\} \\
E_2 &\rightarrow \{P_4, P_8\} \\
E_3 &\rightarrow \{P_3\}
\end{align}
$$

I want to schedule each event once, while also maximizing the time between these events. So in this case, is there an algorithm to find the matches:

$$
\begin{align}
P_1 &\rightarrow E_1 \\
P_3 &\rightarrow E_3 \\
P_8 &\rightarrow E_2
\end{align}
$$

This is optimal because it maximizes the time between events ($2 + 5$), essentially spreading out these events as much as possible. Note that the ordering $P_1, P_4, P_8$ is more desirable than $P_1, P_2, P_8$ because it divides space evenly even though the time between the first and last periods is the same.

The matches that *minimize* the time between events can be found with bipartite graphs, but can this be generalized to maximization?

Comment: Is the time maximized just by making sure the earliest event is as far as possible from the latest event?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Not exactly. Having a spacing of $P_1$, $P_4$, $P_8$ is more desirable than $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_8$. Not exactly sure how to measure this though.

Comment: You could maximize the sum of the squares of the time intervals?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, that's a good objective function that had slipped my mind. My current "solution" is to enumerate all maximum matchings in a bipartite graph between events and periods and then selecting the one that maximizes the squared time differences.